# Jquery Toggle firing multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Fairly new to jQuery. Following various text and tutorials I'm trying to understand how to get the toggle function to work as its been shown in said tutorials. Yet, I'm having issues where it's being fired multiple times.

```
$document.ready(function() {
  $(#myButtonId).click(function() {
  $(#myDivId).toggle(
     function() {
       $(this).addClass("myClass");
       $(this).next().show(); },
     function() {
       $(this).removeClass("myClass");
       $(this).next().hide(); } 
);
});
});
```

It is my current understanding, the above should on button click, toggle on/show the div and add the class "myClass" to the div "myDivId". Then, on button click again, should toggle off/hide the div and remove the class from the div.

However, somehow it's either only calling 1 of the two toggle functions, and it's calling it multiple times.

Comment: What old version of jquery are you using that is supports toggle?

Comment: Just to confirm that this isn't an artifact of missing/changing code when posting here. Are `#myButtonId` and `#myDivId` variable names? Or they should be strings? And, in the second case, in your code, are you using `'`, `"` or `\`` around your string? Edit: Notice that # is not valid in a variable name, so if you meant to use variables but changed the code here, have in mind that this code when posted is invalid.

Comment: As mentioned by @epascarello, I suppose you're trying to use https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/ . This is deprecated as of 1.8 and removed as of 1.9. So it's possible that you're actually using https://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, assuming that you have a button and div like this in your HTML:

```
<button id="myButtonId">Button</button>
<div id="myDivId" class="myClass">Div that toggles</div>
```

You could, in your javascript file, do this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    $('#myButtonId').click(function()
    {
        $('#myDivId').slideToggle(400, function()
            {
                if($(this).is(':visible'))
                { $(this).addClass('myClass'); }
                else
                { $(this).removeClass('myClass'); }
            }
        );
    });
});
```

To explain this bit of code:

- Once the document is ready
- We watch for any click events on the #myButtonId button
- A click on the #myButtonId button will Toggle the #myDivId div at a speed of 400 milliseconds (0.4 seconds). The second parameter of this slideToggle function is a "Callback", which basically defines what you want to do once the toggle animation is finished
- In the callback, we look at whether the toggled element (#myDivId, in this case) is visible or not. If it's visible, we add the 'myClass' class, otherwise we remove that class

I'm not sure what you wanted to do with the $(this).next().hide(); and $(this).next().show(); lines though, it seemed irrelevant to the question, you can just put them back in the "if is visible" condition if you need them. :-)

Comment: I am using version jQuery 2.1.4.  yes the IDs are strings.  Instead of copy&pasting code I typed it all out. So its more so like  $("divID") with double quotations for the selector. Yes, I am using toggle event as noted by user19513069  as I said, I'm merely going through tutorials and textbooks to learn more about the language myself, and it appears though Im using current jQuery I am realizing I am learning out of an outdated book!  And thank you to @helloholahi as that makes it a bit more clear. I tried using toggle for this, as I had not moved onto the slidetoggle/fadetoggle section yet.

Comment: Actually $("#divID") and $('#divID') will do the exact same, it's just a personal preference to use one or the other.
Note the # though, that defines how you target an element with the ID "divID" as in CSS. If you target a "button" element in your HTML, then you would just do $("button"), and if this button has an ID you can either do $("button#btn_id") or just $("#btn_id").

I encourage you to use the latest version of jQuery and look for more recent tutorials, there's probably free courses on youtube. :-) jQuery is relatively easy to learn and a real pleasure to work with, enjoy!